# Warning in command prompt while installing pip

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pip/

I tried to google it but there was no solution

Comment: Are you installing pip or something with pip? Looks like a network issue. Try `ping pypi.python.org`

Comment: What is the _command_ that you have used for installing pip? Please [edit] and paste the full command output, also add your operating-system as tag.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this.

If you are in a corporate setup which uses proxy server for outbound connections, then try following:

Set environment variables for proxy.

Windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver:port
set https_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver:port
```

Mac/Linux:

```bash
export http_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver:port
export https_proxy=http://user:password@proxyserver:port
```

or explicitly use proxy in the pip install command:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port
pip install --upgrade <pakcage-name> --trusted-host pypi.org --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port
```

or you can setup or use an artifactory for python package installations for your org:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host <artifactory-host-name> --index-url <artifactory-url>
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem?